# ERROR 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-209c_8' SQL Statement:

Tags: sql

Why i can'nt add two foreign key?

Executing:

```
ALTER TABLE `adv`.`book` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `BRANCH_ID`
  FOREIGN KEY (`BRANCH_ID`)
  REFERENCES `adv`.`branch` (`BRANCH_ID`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-209c_8'
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `adv`.`book` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `BRANCH_ID`
  FOREIGN KEY (`BRANCH_ID`)
  REFERENCES `adv`.`branch` (`BRANCH_ID`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using MySQL.

From the error message, it is very likely that there is already another constraint that has the same name (ie `BRANCH_ID`). This is not allowed.

To solve the problem, you could simply give a different name to the constraint that you are trying to create.

You can query [catalog view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html) to find out which tables use the same constraint name.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE constraint_name = 'BRANCH_ID';
```